# How to properly retrieve values in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I´m quite new to Javascript and jQuery. For a project I want to check if a Sharepoint list contains any duplicates, without using build in function, to expand it later on to compare more than one column. In my current code I'm retrieving the value of a lookup field and try to match it to all my results in my table. While I properly got my lookup value, my matching variable (x) shows multiple "undefined" entries. When manually typing in the URL, the XML-document shows all the necessary values in my list.

How can I properly retrieve each of my current list values and pass it to a variable?

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- reference jQuery from Miscrosoft CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">

  function PreSaveItem() {
    if (CheckExists()) {
      alert('KU in USE');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function CheckExists() {
    var gnr= $("select[title='Test']").find("option:selected").text();
    alert(gnr) 
    var listUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('My List')/items?$select=*,Test/Test&$expand=Test"; 
    var c = false;
    $.ajax({
      url: listUrl,
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
          var x = item["Test"].text ; 
          alert(x);
          if (x!= undefined) {
            if (gnr === x) {
            c = true;
            }
          }
        }); // each
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    });
    return c;
  }

</script>​​​
```

I expect the output of an alert, if a duplicate is found, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please format your code a little neater? All the whitespace makes the indentation hard to read

Comment: Thanks to DontVoteMeDown for editing my code. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example for your reference.

1.Create custom list "My List".

2.Add lookup field "Test", column look up values from another custom list with the column "ID".

3.Add the code below into script editor web part in new form page in "My List".

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveItem() {
    if (CheckExists()) {
        alert('KU in USE');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
function CheckExists() {
    var gnr= $("select[title='Test']").find("option:selected").text();
    //alert(gnr) 
    var listUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('My List')/Items?$select=Test/Id&$filter=Test/Id eq "+gnr+"&$expand=Test/Id"; 
    var c = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: listUrl,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                c=true;
            }        
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
    return c;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a property/column called "Test" from List "Test".

Instead of using:

```
var x = item["Test"].text
```

Try to use:

```
var x = item.Test.Test
```

Comment: I want to call each item form List "My List" in Column "Test".

Comment: But your column called **"Test"** is a Lookup right? If is not, why are you using expand? 

If your column **"Test"** is not a lookup column, you can use: `var x = item.Test` or `var x = item["Test"]`

Comment: Yeah you are right, it is indeed a lookup column. This column looks up values form a list called "data" and a column named "ID".